# MySQL stored procedure, while loop, union dataset

Tags: mysql

I'm new to stored procedures so I may be doing this wrong. I've created a stored procedure that brings back month name, month start and month end but I'm getting 12 separate datasets.

How can I combine this into one?

```html
BEGIN

SET @i = 0;
SET @start_date = "2018-09-01";
SET @end_date = LAST_DAY('2018-09-01');

WHILE @i < 12 DO
     
    SELECT MONTHNAME(@start_date) AS month, @start_date, @end_date;
    
    SET @i = @i + 1;
    SET @start_date = DATE_ADD(@start_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
    SET @end_date = LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(@end_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
 
END WHILE;

END
```

Comment: Which server version are you using?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel MySQL 8.0

Comment: Do you want the next 12 months or the last 12 months?

Comment: What I want is 12 months starting from September 01 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a stored procedure for that.

```
set @start_date = '2018-09-01';
with recursive months(m) as (
  select 0
  union all
  select m + 1
  from months
  where m < 11
)
select @start_date + interval m.m month as first_day
     , last_day(@start_date + interval m.m month) as last_day
from months m
order by m.m asc
```

Result:

```
first_day   last_day
2018-09-01  2018-09-30
2018-10-01  2018-10-31
2018-11-01  2018-11-30
2018-12-01  2018-12-31
2019-01-01  2019-01-31
2019-02-01  2019-02-28
2019-03-01  2019-03-31
2019-04-01  2019-04-30
2019-05-01  2019-05-31
2019-06-01  2019-06-30
2019-07-01  2019-07-31
2019-08-01  2019-08-31
```

But you can ofcourse use that query in your SP too.

Comment: This is awesome mate. I'm still not familiar with recursive queries or stored procedures so I don't fully understand what is happening with your query but the result set is correct.

If I did want to do it using my SP way, is it possible?

Comment: No one understands what's going on in a recursive CTE ;-) But this one is good to know , if you need sequence numbers.

Comment: Thanks pal. I just read a tutorial and wrote it out again from scratch and it actually makes sense to me now. Thanks a for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote @Paul Spiegel query so that I can understand how recursive queries work.

```html
SET @start = "2018-09-01";

WITH RECURSIVE months (m) 
AS (
      SELECT 0
      UNION ALL
      SELECT m + 1 
      FROM months 
      WHERE m < 12
    )
SELECT
MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD(@start, INTERVAL m MONTH)) AS month_name,
CONCAT(DATE_ADD(@start, INTERVAL m MONTH), " 00:00:00") AS start_of_month,
CONCAT(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(@start, INTERVAL m MONTH)), " 23:59:59") AS end_of_month
FROM months;
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL versions before 8.0 , we can do something like this:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(d.dt + INTERVAL i.n MONTH)  AS month
     , d.dt + INTERVAL i.n MONTH             AS start_date
     , LAST_DAY(d.dt + INTERVAL i.n MONTH)   AS end_date
  FROM ( SELECT '2018-09-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AS dt ) d
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2
         UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
         UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
         UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11
       ) i
 ORDER
    BY i.n
```